# How can I pass okta authentication token to my webdav server through ms-office desktop applications?

Tags: javascript, office365, webdav, okta-api

Question: I have a WebDAV server and I want to implement security with the help of okta. We have an Okta Authorizer on load balancer level, which authenticates each and every request. When I open a document from this WebDAV server on ms-office desktop apps, the Okta login page or something similar does not open and the document fails to load. Is there any way to pass the header via ms-office request? The user should not be prompted for each save request.

Research: I have gone through many articles, plugins, and addons which could support Okta SSO authorization, but didnt helped much. So asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should respond to unauthenticated requests with the WWW-Authenticate header populated with the appropriate bearer realm for Okta.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please add some explanations/references here?